# Is there a way to extract an ID from a URL using Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

The URL starts with an "https://" and has utm parameters added. I want to extract the value of the last utm parameter, which will be unique for the users; and I want to extract this using Oracle SQL. I've tried using the regexp_replace and regexp_substr PHP functions, but I couldn't extract it.

```
https://www.mfashion.in/in/en/department/maxmen?utm_source=ResponsysMailing&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=MaxFashion_Test&LMR_ID=Max_Test_Proof_VP
```

I want to extract "Max_Test_Proof_VP", which is the last parameter. 
This parameter may change for users. Some might have only numeric values and the length might change. But, the variable "LMR_ID=" will be constant.

How do I extract this? 
Please help me with this! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the "last word":

```
SQL> with test (url) as
  2    (select 'https://www.mfashion.in/in/en/department/maxmen?utm_source=ResponsysMailing&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=MaxFashion_Test&LMR_ID=Max_Test_Proof_VP' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(url, '\w+$') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
-----------------
Max_Test_Proof_VP

SQL>
```